# "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference" when trying to make a form switch

Tags: vb.net, forms

I'm making a software that needs to go between a large amount of forms when i click a button. Right now, i have it as

```
 Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
        Me.Visible = False
        SortsTrigger.Show()
End Sub
```

and that seems to bring up the code error. Nothing else is explaining it, How do i fix this?

Comment: Welcome!  Some more information would be helpful... Check out the [tour] (you'll earn your first badge!) as well as "[ask]" and how to create a [mcve].

Comment: Do you have a Form in your Project called "SortsTrigger"? ...or WHERE is this code located? It's hopefully in a Form that contains "Button2". The name of your method, "Button2_Click_1", indicates that you probably had an existing "Button2_Click" method already in your code, then you added Button2 to the Form and double clicked it, causing Visual Studio to add the "_1" on the end to make a different name from the default name handler it would have used.

Answer (score 0):

With the limited code you displayed, I would guess that you have not initialized your other form (assuming that SortTrigger is a reference to a form class object).  Using your original code, here is my suggestion:

```
Private Sub Button2_Click_1(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles 
Button2.Click
    Me.Visible = False

    If SortsTrigger Is Nothing Then
        'Assign the SortsTrigger to a new class reference
        SortsTrigger = New frmSorts 'Or whatever the class name is for this form
    End If
    
    SortsTrigger.Show()
End Sub
```

Comment: If "SortsTrigger" was a variable that is of type Form, and it wasn't initialized, then the error would be a NULL REFERENCE exception, not a "Reference to a non-shared member requires an object reference" error. If "SortsTrigger" is the name of the Form itself then `.Show()` would display the "default instance" without needing to create an instance.  Most likely the error is resulting from some piece of code the original author didn't post. They definitely did not provide enough information to troubleshoot correctly.